# Scan QR and add item to list

Tags: flutter, qr-code, barcode-scanner, flutter-listview

I am new to Flutter. I want to build a Flutter app which scans QR/Bar-code to add item to the list. The QR generation and item detail I will handle in back-end.

I basically need suggestions for "scan and add to list" part in Flutter and how to do it

- Any sample project or docs for similar use case
- Suggestions
- Suggestions for any existing Flutter package/library to solve this easily

Answer (score 1):

you can use this https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner
or just search 'qr' at https://pub.dev/ it will shows bunch of package that you can use

Answer (score -2):

Use flutter_barcode_scanner plugin

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner